# Why would all views in a view have userInteractionEnabled set to NO

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios8

I have a view and for some unknown reason, it's not receiving any touches. When I debugged the view, I've found out that its views' `userInteractionEnabled` is set to `NO`. The problem is that, I haven't set it anywhere; neither in Interface Builder (triple checked) and code. The problem started when I first created the regular UIViewController in Interface Builder, without a subclass or any custom code. I know it's near impossible to tell something without code samples, but my project is heavily complicated, and as I've said, the problem is appearing in a regular UIViewController (no subclass) that I've set in interface builder, so there is no relevant code that would mean anything. The rest of the app just works fine, though.

What can possibly cause all views in a regular, default view controller to become `userInteractionEnabled = NO`?

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer myself after traversing window's recursive description more carefully. I had a scroll view, and inside that, a content view, and other views inside. I'm on pure auto layout, so my scroll view's content view needs to calculate it's own intrinsic size. I was using a placeholder height for the content view in Interface Builder, to make editing interface visually easier. Apparently, I forgot to connect the last view inside my content view to bottom of my content view with a constraint, resulting in my content view having a height of 0 (though still displaying perfectly as it doesn't have clipping enabled). When it's size was 0, it was calculating `userInteractionEnabled` as `NO` automatically without being explicitly set to `NO`. I've added the required bottom constraint and the problem went away.